# Oracle db-connection doesn't work with entity framework: A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory'

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to use the Entity Framework to access my database. The connection itself does work, as shown in the sample. But if i try to access the DbSet in the context the code throws an Exception:

> A null was returned after calling the 'get_ProviderFactory' method on
>   a store provider instance of type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'. The store provider might
>   not be functioning correctly.

My context:

```
Public Class daDbContext
    Inherits System.Data.Entity.DbContext

    Public Property MyTable() As DbSet(Of MyTable)

    Public Sub New(con As OracleConnection)
        MyBase.New(CType(con, DbConnection), contextOwnsConnection:=True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code-Sample:

```
Try
    Dim con As New OracleConnection("Data Source=mydb;Password=mypassword;Persist Security Info=True;" + _
                                    "User ID=myuser;Connection Lifetime=0;Connection Timeout=15;HA Events=false;" + _
                                    "Load Balancing=false;Max Pool Size=100;Min Pool Size=1;Pooling=false;" + _
                                    "Validate Connection=false")

    con.Open()

    ' Try to read data with our connection'
    Dim com As OracleCommand = con.CreateCommand()
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    Dim reader As OracleDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("new connection: " + DirectCast(reader("mycolumn"), String))
        ' Works fine..'
    End While

    ' Init ef-db-context'
    Dim ctx As New daDbContext(con)

    ' Try to read Data with connection from ef-db-context'
    com = DirectCast(ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand(), OracleCommand)
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM mytable"
    reader = com.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine("ctx connection: " + DirectCast(reader("mycolumn"), String))
        ' Works fine..'
    End While

    ' Throws exception'
    Dim l As List(Of MyTable) = ctx.MyTable.ToList()
    Console.WriteLine(l.First().MyColumn)
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
End Try
```

What am i doing wrong? I don't understand why the connection works while the ProviderFactory causes problems.